# Determining distance to nearest location along stream network by each cell using GRASS?

Tags: raster, grass-gis, distance, rivers

I have a river network in raster and locations of many dams on the river.

[image]

In the image above, the **BLUE** point represent one random cell. Dam 1 is downstream to the cell.

I am looking to calculate the distance to the closest dam for each cell. And the distance should be calculate along the river network.

In the above picture, the distance from the blue point to Dam2 should be returned to the blue cell.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem using GRASS? I need the result as a raster file.

---

Some of my guess are given below.

I'm guessing some tools like r.cost?

Comment: Hi, I guess is better if you split the questions in to posts. Then, it is missing something about the way you want to calculate this and get the result. Do you want to produce a raster file with "installed capacity upstream" and another one with "distance to closest utility upstream"? or do you want to do this as a procedure for a single point?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS Desktop and GRASS, and which of your two questions, you wish to ask about in this particular question

Comment: Hi @Marco Thanks for the reply, I need raster results.

Comment: @PolyGeo Hi, the question is edited in accordance with the title, sry for the trouble.

Comment: Feel free to ask the same question but for ArcGIS Desktop as a separate question.  We ask for one question per question so that your question and our answers can focus on precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: I would say this is a network tracing problem and would be much easier than trying to resolve it in a raster format.